# Erro em FK ao executar o Migrations em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, migrations

Estou com o seguinte cenário

```
public class branch()
{
    public Branch()
    {
        Branchs = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TypeDelivery")]
    public long TypeDeliveryId { get;set; }

    public virtual TypeDelivery TypeDeliverys { get; set; }
}
public class TypeDelivery()
{
    public TypeDelivery()
    {
        Branchs = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branchs { get; set; }
}
```

mas quando rodo o update-database no migrations ele retorna o seguinte erro.

> Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
>       The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Branches_dbo.TypeDeliveries_TypeDeliveryId". The conflict occurred in database "PensouChegouProducao", table "dbo.TypeDeliveries", column 'Id'.

se alguem tiver passado por isso me ajudem por favor.

Segue o arquivo de migração.

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Branches", "TypeDeliveryId", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.Branches", "TypeDeliveryId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Branches", "TypeDeliveryId", "dbo.TypeDeliveries", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Branches", "TypeDeliveryId", "dbo.TypeDeliveries");
    DropIndex("dbo.Branches", new[] { "TypeDeliveryId" });
    DropColumn("dbo.Branches", "TypeDeliveryId");
}
```

Comment: Tem como postar o conteúdo do arquivo da migration? Ou você está fazendo update direto, sem utilizar migrações explícitas?

Comment: pronto atualizei na pergunta

Comment: Já existem dados na tabela **`Branches`**, certo?

Comment: sim ja tenho dados nela

Comment: Pois bem, só ver minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque já existem dados na tabela `dbo.Branches`.

Veja, você está criando uma coluna **obrigatória**, ou seja, que não pode ter valor nulo. Ao criar esta coluna, automaticamente o SQL Server precisa colocar um valor para os registros existentes.

E qual é o valor padrão pra uma coluna numérica? Isso mesmo, zero, *nihil*.

Colocando o valor desta coluna como zero, espera-se que exista alguma linha na outra ponta da relação (na tabela **`dbo.TypeDeliveries`**) que contenha esta chave primária e isso não existe, por isso estoura este erro.

Limpe a tabela antes de rodar a *migration* ou defina um valor padrão para a coluna.